# python3 is broken on Ubuntu 20.04 and I am unable to fix it

Tags: apt, permissions, python, 20.04

I somehow messed up the python3 environment in my Ubuntu 20.04 (upgraded from 19.10). I do not know how this exactly happened, but after rebooting I am not able to start the gnome-terminal anymore. Note that up to now I it has been running fine since I upgraded about 2 weeks ago.

I suspect that this might be due to a bad `chmod` command, which I ran with `sudo` during the session before restarting my laptop. I am not 100% sure though, because I ran that `chmod` command inside the folder of a software-project (to fix permissions) and I really would have had to mess up the command to do this damage.

Right now I am unable to install python3 to fix the system and I cannot update/reinstall on the system (to maybe fix permissions of the python3 package), because everything depends on python3.

Here is what I have tried so far:

Starting gnome-terminal from XTerm I get this error:

```
root@ierbert2:/home/micha# gnome-terminal
bash: /usr/bin/gnome-terminal: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

`ll /usr/bin/python*` returns:

```
root@/****:/home/****# ll /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       7 Apr 15 12:45 /usr/bin/python -> python2*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mär 13 13:31 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3694632 Apr  7 14:05 /usr/bin/python2.7*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 Mär 13 13:20 /usr/bin/python3 -> python3.8
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 5457536 Apr 27 17:53 /usr/bin/python3.8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 Apr 27 17:53 /usr/bin/python3.8-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.8-config*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Mär 13 13:20 /usr/bin/python3-config -> python3.8-config*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     384 Mär 28 03:39 /usr/bin/python3-futurize*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     388 Mär 28 03:39 /usr/bin/python3-pasteurize*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     152 Apr  9 21:32 /usr/bin/python3-pbr*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     384 Dez 17 13:47 /usr/bin/python3-unit2*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      58 Feb 18 02:49 /usr/bin/pythontex -> ../share/texlive/texmf-dist/scripts/pythontex/pythontex.py*
```

I tried reinstalling the python3 package using `apt-get` and `dpkg`, which both fail:

Using with `apt-get install` option:

```
root@******:/home/****# sudo apt-get install python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3 is already the newest version (3.8.2-0ubuntu2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/47,6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Using with `apt-get install --reinstall` option:

```
root@******:/home/****# sudo apt-get install --reinstall python3
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly instaslled, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/47,6 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 325889 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: 5: py3clean: Permission denied
dpkg: warning: old python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 5: py3clean: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: 47: py3compile: Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Using `dpkg`:

```
root@****:/home/****# dpkg -i /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb 
(Reading database ... 325889 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.prerm: 5: py3clean: Permission denied
dpkg: warning: old python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/prerm: 5: py3clean: Permission denied
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb (--install):
 new python3 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 126
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3.postinst: 47: py3compile: Permission denied
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed python3 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 126
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3_3.8.2-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb
```

Comment: What exact `chmod` command? Don't guess: Check your `~/.bash_history` file and get it right. It matters.

Comment: @user535733 Thanks for the pointer to `~/.bash_history`. I was not aware, that I could check the history the way. So the two command I ran were `sudo chmod -R +x` and `sudo chown -R myuser:myuser` with either `*` or `.` as argument. From what I can tell from the history, I ran them all in/on the correct folder (or at least not even close to system-root level). I also checked this by looking at the permissions of relevant files.

Comment: @user535733 I just realized that there were two more commands: `sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} +` and `sudo find . *.py -exec chmod 664 {} +`. But here again I am pretty sure, they ran on the correct folders.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. Somehow `/usr/bin/python3.8` lost the executable bit (likely because of me messing up a command; it was a long day). I fixed it by running:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/python3.8
```

Comment: Come to think about it: pretty "amazing" (but not surprising) that one bit can give you the impression, that the whole Ubuntu install is broken.